# The adjoint of unbounded operators as a function.

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $H_1$, $H_2$ be two possibly distinct real or complex Hilbert spaces, with linearity in the first coordinate of the inner product for concreteness.  Let's think of passage to the adjoint as a map from the $A$ to $B$ where $A$ and $B$ are defined as follows:

$A:= \{S:D(S)\rightarrow H_2|S \text{ is a densely defined operator with domain in } H_1\}$

$B:= \{T:D(T)\rightarrow H_1|T \text{ is a closed operator with domain in } H_2\}$

I stress that I didn't say "densely defined" anywhere in the definition of $B$.

Is there an equivalence relation on $A$ roughly capturing the idea of being "densely equal" with the property that modding out by it would make passage to the adjoint injective?  Is passage to the adjoint surjective?